# How to get python turtle to move according to a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, turtle-graphics

```
import turtle as t
from turtle import *
from math import sin, pi, sqrt
setup(500, 500)
Screen()
title("Turtle Art")
showturtle()
screen = Screen()
yertle = Turtle()

turn = 90
speed = 10
moves = []

def k1():
    t.forward(speed)
    moves.append(1)

def k2():
    t.left(turn)
    moves.append(2)

def k3():
    t.right(turn)
    moves.append(3)

def k4():
    t.backward(speed)
    moves.append(4)

def k102():
    if input("Would you like to save this? (y/n) ") == "y":
        name = input("What would you like to call your masterpiece? ")
        my_file = open("./%s" % (name), "w")
        global moves
        moves = str(moves)
        my_file.write(moves)
        my_file.close()
        print("It has been saved as:", name)
    else:
        t.clear

t.onkey(k1, "Up") #move forwards
t.onkey(k2, "Left") #turn left
t.onkey(k3, "Right") #turn right
t.onkey(k4, "Down") # move backwards

t.onkey(k102, "p") #save page

listen()
mainloop()
```

This saves it as a list in a text file in the current folder (that looks like this: [1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1]). I was wondering how to make the turtle reproduce this by moving according to the 1, 2, 3, or 4. Is there any way to read from a text file easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading evokes several questions, "Do you want to be able to load over an existing drawing to augment it?", "Do you want to give the user the opportunity to save the current drawing before loading another?", "Should you clear the drawing before loading?".  The following solution tries to allow all these possibilities, letting the user save, clear and/or load one drawing on top of another which can be saved as a more complex drawing:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

ANGLE = 90
DISTANCE = 10

def k1():
    yertle.forward(DISTANCE)
    moves.append(1)

def k2():
    yertle.left(ANGLE)
    moves.append(2)

def k3():
    yertle.right(ANGLE)
    moves.append(3)

def k4():
    yertle.backward(DISTANCE)
    moves.append(4)

COMMANDS = {1: k1, 2: k2, 3: k3, 4: k4}

def save():
    if moves and input('Would you like to save this drawing? (y/n) ').lower().startswith('y'):
        name = input('What would you like to call your drawing? ')

        with open(name, 'w') as my_file:
                    print(*moves, sep=', ', file=my_file)

        print('Drawing has been saved as:', name)

def clear():
    global moves

    save()

    if moves and input('Would you like to erase this drawing? (y/n) ').lower().startswith('y'):
        moves = []
        yertle.reset()

def load():
    clear()

    if input('Would you like to load a drawing? (y/n) ').lower().startswith('y'):
        name = input('What would drawing would you like to load? ')

        with open(name) as my_file:
            commands = [int(digit) for digit in my_file.readline().split(',')]

        for command in commands:
            if command in COMMANDS:
                COMMANDS[command]()

        print('Drawing has been loaded from:', name)


screen = Screen()
screen.setup(500, 500)
screen.title('Turtle Art')

moves = []

yertle = Turtle('turtle')

screen.onkey(k1, 'Up')  # move forwards
screen.onkey(k2, 'Left')  # turn left
screen.onkey(k3, 'Right')  # turn right
screen.onkey(k4, 'Down')  # move backwards

screen.onkey(clear, 'c')  # clear page
screen.onkey(save, 'p')  # save page
screen.onkey(load, 'l')  # load page

screen.listen()

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: this works perfectly thank you, i will add this to my project

Answer (score 0):

This file IO tutorial for python should help: http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python

You are going to want to pay special attention to the section on splitting lines. You may want to split lines based on commas instead of spaces.

Using a loop to go through the text file may not be necessary if you only have one line. If you split the line correctly, it should give you a nice array of numbers that correspond to the moves the turtle should make. Something like:

```
file = open("movefile.txt","r")
moves = file.readline().split(",")
```

may work. It all depends on how the text file that contains the pre-existing moves is set up.

Edit:

It may be helpful to write the moves to the textfile in a different way. It will save you some headache when trying to read them. Instead of saying, `my_file.write(moves)`, it may be better to use:

```
for i in moves:
     my_file.write(str(i)+",")
```

This should make your text file look something like "1,1,1,2,3,3,1,"

With this format the first piece of code i put should work to get all the numbers into the "moves" array. I suggest changing that array name to something like "moves_from_file". Once you have that...

```
for j in moves_from_file:
     if moves_from_file[j] == "1":
         k1()
     if moves_from_file[j] == "2":
         k2()
     if moves_from_file[j] == "3":
         k3()
     if moves_from_file[j] == "4":
         k4()
```

should do the trick.

Comment: how do i implement this into my programming? Do i just say ...readline(1)...? or do i need to say if moves=file.readline().split(",") = 1?

Comment: also, to make the turtle actually move, how do i say read word 1, if it says 1 then move forwards, if it says 2, turn right. for example.

Comment: First you want to get the numbers from the text file into an array. In the case that I set above that array name is "moves". Once you have that, then you want to loop through your array with a for loop and check the number at each spot in the array, and do the corresponding move. something like `for i in moves:  if moves[i] == 1, do k1(), if moves[i] == 2, do k2()` something like that @Gurneyguy

Comment: @Gurneyguy I edited the above answer to try to make things a bit more clear.

Comment: will this make the actions happen in the order according to the list?

Comment: when i use the `for i in moves: my_file.write(str(i)+",")` it gives the output to the file: [,1,,, ,1,0,2,], which has way too many commas in to do anything useful with, surely.

Comment: The if statements should just make sure that it only does the actions if that number comes up.

Comment: try `if i != "[", if i != "]", my_file.write(str(i)+" ")`